# Unmodifiable List of modifiable objects

Tags: java, list, unmodifiable

Let's say we have got a `List<List<String>>` and want to make it completely unmodifiable. Simply passing it to a `Collection.unmodifiableList` would not suffice because the inner Lists can still be modified.

I would go with the following approach:

```
List<List<String>> someList;
```

Make it unmodifiable:

```
List<List<String>> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
for(List<String> strList : someList) {
    tempList.add(Collections.unmodifiableList(strList));
}
List<List<String>> safeList = Collections.unmodifiableList(tempList);
```

Is this approach okay?

Comment: I think it should work fine

Comment: What's wrong with wrapping it in a container of your own?

Comment: Of course, if your lists contain mutable objects (eg, a StringBuilder vs a String), those would still be mutable.

Comment: What are you trying to do (from a class / requirement point of view). This sure looks like there is a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: The List is a private member of an object. This object should be able to modify the list. But other objects should be able to read the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach should work, as long as you don't keep references to the original, modifiable, lists. Such references could modify the lists wrapped by the unmodifiable lists.

Answer (score 1):

The way to achieve immutability is to create **defensive copies.**

#### Data in

Whenever a mutable object is passed to your method(s), you create a deep copy of it. This should be the first thing you do, even before you check validity, if you want maximum security.

Wrapping a list into a `Collections.unmodifiableList()` isn't going to work here because there's no guarantee that the underlying list won't be modified by a third party. In other words, you're not in control of the instance.

A good way of creating immutable copies of lists is by using Google Guava's `ImmutableList.copyOf()` method, but remember that you need a deep copy, so you need to create immutable copies of the lists within the main list.

#### Data out

whenever you return a value, you make another defensive copy, so that changes to the returned object don't reflect back. Here you can use unmodifiable wrappers (e.g. `ImmutableList.of()`) on your lists because you're holding the only reference to the original list.

If you do both (copy on the way in, copy/wrap on the way out), your code will be safe and correct. Any other solution and no such general guarantees can be given, your code may or many not be correct.

Comment: You are right on target. The above code which I shared does validate your first point

Answer (score 1):

I feel it doesnot work:-

```
    List<List<String>> someList = new ArrayList<>();

            List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            l1.add("STR1");
            l1.add("STR2");
            l1.add("STR3");

            l2.add("STR4");
            l2.add("STR5");
            l2.add("STR6");

            someList.add(l1);
            someList.add(l2);

            List<List<String>> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(List<String> strList : someList) {
                tempList.add(Collections.unmodifiableList(strList));
            }
            List<List<String>> safeList = Collections.unmodifiableList(tempList);

            l1.add("STR7"); // The inner list reference is modified which causes the 
safelist internal structure to get changed

            for(List<String> safeInnerList : safeList) {
                System.out.println(safeInnerList);

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code should do :-

```
            List<List<String>> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(List<String> strList : someList) {
                tempList.add(new ArrayList<>(strList));
            }
            List<List<String>> safeList = Collections.unmodifiableList(tempList);
```

Here goes the test for this :-

```
List<List<String>> someList = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        l1.add("STR1");
        l1.add("STR2");
        l1.add("STR3");

        l2.add("STR4");
        l2.add("STR5");
        l2.add("STR6");

        someList.add(l1);
        someList.add(l2);

        List<List<String>> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(List<String> strList : someList) {
            tempList.add(new ArrayList<>(strList));
        }
        List<List<String>> safeList = Collections.unmodifiableList(tempList);

        l1.add("STR7"); // The inner list reference is modified this doesnot cause the safelist internal structure to get changed

        for(List<String> safeInnerList : safeList) {
            System.out.println(safeInnerList);
        }
```